# Breaking inductive hypothesis into 2 groups

Tags: proof-writing, induction, fake-proofs

I remember that we had a lecture in which during the inductive step, we proved P(n) by breaking the n+1 terms into two groups. The below question is marked as an incorrect approach on the practice sets. When is using such an approach (breaking n+1 things into two groups) valid?

[image]

Comment: Hint:  these things usually go wrong when you pass from the base case, $k=1$,  to $k=2$

Comment: @lulu In other words, $n=1$ isn't actually the "true" base case.

Comment: @Arthur  Sure.  If you could prove it for $k=2$, the induction really would go through.